# ASCII file in Eclipse plugin project not visible after export

Tags: java, file, build, eclipse-plugin, export

Am am working on an Eclipse plugin project. Inside that project I have a folder `resources`, which contains a simple ASCII file, which contains lines with `String`s. These `String`s are used in a drop down menu, by the ui. If I run a new launchtime Eclipse everything works like it should and the file content is successfully used by the drop down menu but if I **export** the application and run it, the drop down menu is empty, which means, that the file can't be read.

Inside the `plugin.xml` (Build tab) I've marked the resource folder (which contains the ASCII file) in the binary build.

This is how I extract the file line by line:

```
public class ParameterExtractor {

    private final static String FILE_PATH = "/resources/parameters";

    public ArrayList<String> extractParameters() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
        URL url = FileLocator.resolve(getClass().getResource(FILE_PATH));
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = url.toURI();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (uri != null) {
            try {
                File file = new File(uri);
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    params.add(line);
                }
                fileReader.close();
            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return params;
    }
}
```

And this is how I use the returned `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    params = new ParameterExtractor().extractParameters();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
final Combo combo = new Combo(container, SWT.BORDER);
combo.setItems(params.toArray(new String[params.size()]));
```

What could cause the problem and how can I solve it?

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileLocator.resolve` does not guarantee to return you a URL than can be used to read a file. Instead use:

```
Bundle bundle = ... your plugin bundle

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(FILE_PATH), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

The URL returned by `toFileURL` is suitable for reading using `File` and `FileReader`.